# Jmeter file upload in HTTP Post

Tags: jmeter, http-post

[image]Am trying to upload a file in Jmeter to test a Rest API using HTTP post request. XML data and a file needs to be posted to Rest Service to create an invoice, but when I click on the `File Upload` tab am seeing below warning, am a newbie in Jmeter so am really sure how this can be done

Can someone please tell me how do I upload file for HTTP Post request in Jmeter (3.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can only choose one from "Parameters" "Body Data" and "Files Upload", if you want to upload file in the request, please leave "Body Data" blank.